# Django Rest framework router ModelViewSet

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I want to use ModelViewSet in router.

But I want to choose `list` `retrieve` `destroy`.

#### views

```
class UsersView(ModelViewSet):
    ...
```

I know it can

#### views

```
class UsersView(mixins.RetrieveModelMixin,
                mixins.DestroyModelMixin,
                mixins.ListModelMixin,
                GenericViewSet):
     ...
```

#### urls

```
router = DefaultRouter()
router.register(r'users', UsersView)
urlpatterns += router.urls
```

Is there a better way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the best way, there is no other way.